# Pandas: Fillna with local average if a condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have data like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [5, np.nan, 2, 2, 5, np.nan, 4], 'col2':[1,3,np.nan,np.nan,5,np.nan,4]})
print(df)
   col1  col2
0   5.0   1.0
1   NaN   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
3   2.0   NaN
4   5.0   5.0
5   NaN   NaN
6   4.0   4.0
```

How can I use `fillna()` to replace NaN values with the average of the prior and the succeeding value **if both of them are not NaN** ?

The result would look like this:

```
   col1  col2
0   5.0   1.0
1   3.5   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
3   2.0   NaN
4   5.0   5.0
5   4.5   4.5
6   4.0   4.0
```

Also, is there a way of calculating the average from the previous n and succeeding n values (if they are all not NaN) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can shift the dataframe forward and backwards. Then add these together and divide them by two and use that to fillna:

```
s1, s2 = df.shift(), df.shift(-1)
df = df.fillna((s1 + s2) / 2)
```

```
   col1  col2
0   5.0   1.0
1   3.5   3.0
2   2.0   NaN
3   2.0   NaN
4   5.0   5.0
5   4.5   4.5
6   4.0   4.0
```